# simple if statements waiting for further input in interactive shell

Tags: bash

It seems that my environment has changed such that if/else statements do not work. Typing this in the terminal:

```
if true; then echo 1; else echo 2; fi;
```

will wait for another token (with a `>` prompt), not executing as expected.

I've tried writing this statement in other bash environments, and it prints "1" to stdout, as expected. I have no idea what I did to make my if statements not work.

Comment: The code you posted works for me. It seems you're not showing us the whole code, which makes it impossible to help you.

Comment: Typing that command in my terminal does not work. The prompt waits for another character to be input. That said, it's not that my syntax is wrong, but that something has changed in my environment that makes the syntax wrong. Other bash syntax works, just if/else does not. Any idea why?

Comment: what is the output of `type if` ??

Comment: probably not bash... check your shell.

Comment: what is the output of `if true; then echo yes; fi` ??

Comment: Check with your system administrator. Your login shell may have changed.

Comment: and what is the output of `echo "$IFS" | od -An -vt 'x1c'` ?

Comment: @Robert, that code may "work", but it doesn't do what the OP wants it to. It's checking whether `1=1` is a non-empty string, not comparing the `1` on the left to the `1` on the right. Thus, it would also say that `0=1` was true as well.

Comment: @CamHashemi, run `set -x` as a command, which will make the shell log all subsequent commands that are run.

Comment: @CamHashemi, ...btw, are you entering content **exactly** as given here? If you were leaving off the final `;`, for instance, then hidden characters (such as CRs) could prevent your `fi` from being parsed as such. This is a common problem when copying scripts that were written on other platforms (ie. DOS systems) over to UNIX machines.

Comment: (Similarly: Typing by hand, or copying-and-pasting? If the latter, the clipboard can potentially contain nonprintable characters).

Comment: ...if this is strictly an interactive bug, rather than one that can be reproduced when running a script from a file, you might consider [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) -- this is generally where the line between what's a programming question and what's an end-user question regarding the shell tends to be drawn.

Comment: ...btw, another thing you might look for is aliases. If you have one named `fi`, for instance, there's your problem. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy About aliases: That's why I asked for `type if` output.

Comment: @sorontar, it can't be `if` that's aliased -- we wouldn't get into the parser state in question, at least without it doing something else that starts a compound command; and `else` would just be a syntax error in that scenario. `fi`, though, could be our culprit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Try `alias if=echo` and then the line from the user. Indeed an alias of `if` (or `then` or `fi`) could well be the problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: `alias if='{ if'` :-). Given that the question is not about the spacing error, why did you close it as duplicate?

Comment: @rici, I had the same initial read that led to the existing answer. Frankly, on review, I agree that it's not a duplicate, but it's also not a good question without some editing: I can't see a way this won't fall under the rubric of "resolved in a way unlikely to help others", unless given a title and summary that'll filter for folks with the same actual problem. Right now, it *reads* very much as the "missing-spaces-around-the-operator" question that both sorontar and I took it for at first glance, and I don't feel so bad about leaving it that way until it's improved.

Comment: @rici, ...and you've motivated me to make that improvement myself. *Hopefully* the assumptions are accurate -- would have been better if the OP had done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most plausible situation here is that an element of your syntax is being overridden by an alias. Consider for instance:

```
alias fi=file
if true; then echo 1; fi
```

...will thus read to the shell as:

```
if true; then echo 1; file
```

...and it'll still be waiting for more input.

---

Consider using functions instead of aliases to avoid this kind of problem. For instance:

```
fi() { file "$@"; }
```

...will properly report a syntax error, rather than letting you define something with a dangerous name.

Comment: Another possibility is that the spaces following the semicolons are actually U+00A0 (non-breaking space). That will prevent the words `then`, `else` and `fi` from being recognized as such (since they are actually preceded by what bash considers a non-whitespace character) and so bash will still be looking for a real `then`, so it will prompt again.

Comment: Charles Duffy was right. I had an alias named `fi` for "fix imports". Renaming the alias fixed it.